# Sort list of lists creating another mapping list with index values

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

So i have an original list of lists **oList**, child lists are sequences of numbers. I create another list **srt** to manipulate the data like that:

```
#...
srt = []
for i in range(len(oList)):
    srt.append([ int(oList[i][0]), int(oList[i][2]), i ])
```

So each element of **srt** is [*n0*,*n2*,*idx*] (or something like that, main point is that i keep index of original element from **oList** as last element)...
Now i want to sort it via(*n0*,*n2*...*ni*) with indexing as creation of another mapping list of *idx*. `srt.sort()` does the first part just fine, but generating mapping manually seems inefficient to me.

So i want **srt** to be sorted by both *n0*, *n1* ... *ni* and another list **map** to contain indexes of original elements.
And while processing data in a loop i want to be able (when i need to) to get some element from **srt** via *idx* like that: `something = srt[map[idx]][0]`

Example:

```
# srt=[ [12,8,0], [-4,4,1], [-4,-2,2], [6,8,3], ]
map, srt = custom_sort_here(srt)
# srt=[ [-4,-2,2], [-4,4,1], [6,8,3], [12,8,0], ]
# map=[ 3, 1, 0, 2, ]
# here i can get element with idx=2 from srt like:
el = srt[map[2]]
```

P.S. atm i have my indexing performed AFTER the sorting as a loop:

```
#...
srt.sort()
map = range(len)
for x in range(len):
    map[srt[x][2]]=x #for 2-number lists where idx at [2]
```

So it is very inefficient, and that's the reason for my question - i mean it's definitely possible to create mapping structure WHILE sorting, and i just don't know how cuz i'm new to Python...

P.P.S. if u wonder why i want such weird behaviour - it has something to do with 3D mesh processing, so i really need to keep original point values + polygon data while manipulating duplicate point array of projected [2]coords and/or discreet (approximated) [3]coord values of the original points. Looping thru them along the axis/vectors while sometimes still get some points via indexes according to polygon edge connections. So i REALLY need that kind of data layout.

Comment: -Is- it very inefficient?  You're doing the hard work, the O(nlogn) part, at C speed.  Then you have an O(n) part afterward at CPython (?) speed.  You could modify one of the sorts at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/sort-comparison/ , to change how the indexing and swaps are done (at CPython speed), to eliminate the O(n) step (doing the sort in time O(nlogn), but at CPython speed) but you may find you're better off with what you have already.  Keep in mind that although a little complicated, Timsort is often "supernaturally fast" and stable.

Comment: Well nice point, it's just that i want to optimize EVERYTHING i can cuz the other parts already pretty complex =)) As to CPython - i don't sure how it works, it is a python plugin for Cinema4D i work on. It is definitely gets compiled, but i don't know if it's a bytecode or pure binary...

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for, but to be sure would need a complete worked example with expected output.

```
srt= [ [12,8,0], [-4,4,1], [-4,-2,2], [6,8,3] ]

srt_enum = dict(sorted(enumerate(srt), key=lambda x: x[1]))

# {2: [-4, -2, 2], 1: [-4, 4, 1], 3: [6, 8, 3], 0: [12, 8, 0]}

srt_enum_lst = sorted(srt_enum.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

# [(2, [-4, -2, 2]), (1, [-4, 4, 1]), (3, [6, 8, 3]), (0, [12, 8, 0])]

srt_enum[2]

# [-4, -2, 2]
```

Comment: Well, it works, but it's not the *indexing*. Such approach has a dict structure + list structure with duplicate data + also list has excessive extra hierarchy level with duplicate indexes. I like my manual indexing much more, even tho it's ineffective cuz performed AFTER sorting and i guess it is done in nonpythonish way, cuz im newbie in Python...

Comment: @Markus_13, if the performance of these tasks is poor, consider Cyton or just plain C for customised structures. But first I'd confirm that this really is a  bottleneck for your application.

Comment: Well as i said in the comment to main post: i want to optimize EVERYTHING i can cuz the other parts already pretty complex =))
Obviously it's not the bottleneck, but the thing is - i simply CAN'T simplify or optimize the mesh processing part, so i want to optimize everything else what i can. + also it's for learning purposes cuz i study Python, and i can't believe there r no way to create indexing structures on the fly while sorting...